# Network Error when click <nuxt-link/> in NUXT?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Network error when click `<nuxt-link/>`,

this is my error details, but when i refresh the link, everything is good ? why ?

[image: nuxt-link error]

this is my entire code ,...

`````
    <template>
      <div>
        <nuxt-child/>
        <h1>Videos</h1>
        <div v-for="video in $store.state.videos" :key="video.id">
          <nuxt-link :to="`/videos/${video.id}`">{{ video.customerName }}</nuxt-link>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      export default {
        head:{
            title: 'Customer List'
          },
        async fetch({$axios, store}) {
    
            let response = await $axios.get('/customers');
            let videos = response.data;
    
            store.commit('SET_VIDEOS', videos);
        },
      }
    </script>
    
    <style lang="scss" scoped>
    
    </style>````
`````

Answer (score 1):

Your API request is cross-origin as `localhost:3000` differs from `localhost:8000`

Your API needs to respond to the request on `/api/customers` with a header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. This enables the API to be called from any origin page. Ideally in the future you would want to replace this "wildcard" `*` with the actual origin but for testing this is fine.

I assume your API is an Express one, in this case adding this to your application would force all requests to utilise a wildcard CORS:

```
// Set middlware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // URL of website to allow or a wildcard
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Continue to next layer of request/middleware
    next();
});
```

Alternatively you could also set the origin to `http://localhost:8000`

As a side note, in your example code I see you are using the Vuex store and have a method to make the API call before committing to the store.

If you ever plan on repeating this API call on another component, it would be advised to turn your function into an action within the Vuex store so it is in one central, reusable place.